# dismiss message in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

Hope this doesn't sound ridiculous, but how can I **discard a message** in Camel *on purpose*?

Until now, I sent them to the Log-Component, but meanwhile I don't even want to log the withdrawal.

Is there a **/dev/null** Endpoint in Camel?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the message filter eip to filter out unwanted messages.
http://camel.apache.org/message-filter

There is no dev/null, component.

Also there is a < stop /> you can use in the route, and when a message hit that, it will stop continue routing.

And the closest we got on a dev/null, is to route to a log, where you set logLeve=OFF as option.

Comment: Thank you Claus, the .stop() part is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: So... the syntax as understand would be `log:foo?level=OFF`. This can be useful where the endpoint is defined from a property, like `.to("{{my.route.out}}")` and you don't want to change the route itself (just the property, for testing or what not).

Comment: Unwanted filtered out messages still executes the callback, i.e., sending reply, just like `stop()`. It will reply the same message to reply queue, so filter is not option. But I think log will do(kind of), even it has risk of memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

With credit to my colleague (code name: cayha)...

You can use the [Stub Component](http://camel.apache.org/stub.html) as a camel endpoint that is equivalent to `/dev/null`.

e.g.

```
activemq:route?abc=xyz
```

becomes

```
stub:activemq:route?abc=xyz
```

Although I am not aware of the inner workings of this component (and if there are dangers for memory leaks, etc), it works for me and I can see no drawbacks in doing it this way.

Comment: Just a warning that we've used `stub` in the past and it has caused huge memory usage, as (by default) it appears to retain everything it receives.

Comment: @icabod thanks, good to know. If the `stub:` is isolated to testing then it shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

one can put uri/mock-uri to the config using [property component](http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html)

```
<camelContext ...>
   <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="ref:myProperties"/>
</camelContext>

// properties
cool.end=mock:result
# cool.end=result

// route
from("direct:start").to("properties:{{cool.end}}");
```

Comment: mock will cause memory leaks since it persists as a soft reference that the garbage collection won't be able to process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party but you can set a flag on the exchange and use that flag to skip only that message (by calling stop) if it doesn't meet your conditions.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
  from()
      .process(new Processor() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
          exchange.setProperty("skip", false);
          byte[] messageBytes = exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class);
          if (<shouldNotSkip>) {

          } else { //skip
            exchange.setProperty("skip", true);
          }
        }
      }).choice()
          .when(exchangeProperty("skip").isEqualTo(true))
            .stop()
          .otherwise()
            .to();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using activemq route and needs to send reply in normal cases, so exchange pattern is `InOut`. When I configure a filter in the route I find that even it does not pass message to next step, the callback is executed(sending reply), just same as the behavior when calling `stop()`. And it will send the same message back to reply queue, which is not desirable.

What I do is to change the exchange pattern to `InOnly` conditionally and stop if I want to filter out the message, so reply is not sent. `MAIN_ENDPOINT` is a `direct:main` endpoint I defined to include normal business logic.

```java
from("activemq:queue:myqueue" + "?replyToSameDestinationAllowed=true")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Correlation id is: ${header.JMSCorrelationID}; will ignore if not null")
    .choice()
        .when(simple("${header.JMSCorrelationID} == null"))
            .to(MAIN_ENDPOINT)
        .endChoice()
        .otherwise()
            .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
            .stop()
        .endChoice()
    .end();
```

Note that this message is also consumed and not in the queue anymore. If you want to preserve the message in the queue(not consuming it), you may just `stop()` or just `filter()` so the callback(sending reply which is the original message) works, putting the message back to the queue.

Using only `filter()` would be much simpler:

```java
from("activemq:queue:myqueue" + "?replyToSameDestinationAllowed=true")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Correlation id is: ${header.JMSCorrelationID}; will ignore if not null")
    .filter(simple("${header.JMSCorrelationID} == null"))
    .to(MAIN_ENDPOINT);
```