# Apache Camel stream to /dev/null?

Tags: apache-camel

With Apache Camel, is there a way to stream content to /dev/null? 
For example, would the following work:

```
<to uri="stream:file?fileName=/dev/null" />
```

Or would I just change my /dev/null device file into a normal file, assuming I have the appropriate permissions to do that?

Regards,
Matt

Comment: What is the reason for doing this?

Comment: To simulate load on a NAS streaming large binary files to measure the performance of the NAS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582902/dismiss-message-in-apache-camel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it?

The real answer is that any special functionality with /dev/null for the stream component depends on the underlying operating system and perhaps the particular JVM implementation.

Streaming to /dev/null with Apache Camel, works according to my experience.

Comment: Yes, I did test it in a VM. However, it seems "stream:" needs to pull the entire file into memory, which resulted in JVM crash. I've ended up writing my own processor to read and throw away bytes.

Comment: yeah the file component works better as it can stream directly to the file, so use that instead.

Comment: @ClausIbsen using an endpoint `file:/dev/null` make my route always to retry several times like there's no right to write on it. I think the `log:trash?level=OFF` is a better alternative, otherwise please add the exact url to use /dev/null with file endpoint.